# How can I go to specific URL programmatically in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How can I go to specific URL programmatically in Silverlight?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on what you mean, most likely like this:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate("url");
```

Comment: That's close, its `HtmlPage.Window.Navigate`

Comment: Whoops, you're right. Sorry. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190502(VS.95).aspx